# Changing text on a Button with WPF binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am using WPF and trying to use binding to make buttons work, I am more at home in WinForms but have just started with WPF and MVVM and am a bit lost. I have some buttons already working, I used GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf only because that was what was already in use.

I now have a PAUSE button (text on button = PAUSE) which when pressed will stop the sequence and the text on the button will change to RESUME. I have it bound and can stop the sequence and resume it OK.

In the XML I have

```
<Button Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Name="{Binding onPauseCommand}" Content="Pause" Height="37" Width="88" Command="{Binding onPauseCommand}" />
```

The name is what I think I need to bind to something and as you see at the moment it is just bound to onPauseCommand which you will rightly say is wrong. I agree it does nothing.

In the model view I have

public bool _pause;

```
public bool Pause
{
    get => _pause;
    set
    {
        if (_pause != value)
        {
            _pause = value;
        }
    }
}

public string _btn_pause_text;

public string Btn_Pause_Text
{
    get => _btn_pause_text;
    set
    {
        if (_btn_pause_text != value)
        {
            _btn_pause_text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I also have the buttons bound command, which while it may not be the best implementation sets _pause correctly. I know this is not the place for the _btn_pause_text but this is just showing what I tried. If this was a Winform you woudl say something like btn_pause.Text = "Resume" or btn_pause.Text = "Pause".

//Used to Pause the Sequence
public ICommand onPauseCommand => new RelayCommand(onPause);

```
private void onPause()
{
    if (_pause == false)
    {
        _pause = true; //set to pause sequence
        _btn_pause_text = "Resume";
    }
    else
    {
        _pause = false;
        _btn_pause_text = "Pause";
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to change the buttons text please?

Comment: You have to bind the Content of the Button, not its Name. The source property of the Binding must fire a change notification, typically the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. If the code that changes the Button Content is in the code behind of the view, you may also directly set it without a Binding. Assign a name to the Button like `x:Name="myButton"` and access it in code behind like `myButton.Content = "Resume";`

Comment: Thanks I have just found this very nice control that does what I want called Togglebutton